# How to Spark python UDF: unregister or register to overwrite function of same name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

```
f = lambda x: str(x) 
with SparkContext("local", "HelloWorld") as sc:
     spark = SQLContext(sc)
     spark.udf.register("f", f)
```

This code works to register the python udf once so it can be called such as with:

```
 %sql "select f(col_name) from table_name"
```

But the function does not change the next time this gets called (after f has been redefined)! How do you redefine a udf, i.e. re-register it so as the overwrite the old udf. Is there a drop_udf function, etc.?

Comment: have you tried calling `spark.udf.register("f", f)` after f has been redefined?

Comment: yes it was another bug, this seems to work now, not sure why it wasn't... thank you